# Calculate std of Kalman Filter

Tags: std, kalman-filter

I developed Kalman filter (for k=1 to 100)
How I calculate the filter standard-deviations ?

In the first question i show the Monte-Carlo (30 runs) means of the estimation errors are almost 0, and now I need to show that KF stds are very close to the Monte-Carlo standard deviations.
I would appreciate help on how to calculate the KF std

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the standard deviation the square root of the mean of squares minus the square of neam?  You'll find the formula on wikipedia in about 5 seconds.

Comment: My question is on which variable do I calculate the STD

Comment: ? measurement? Update? Prediction? Error?

Comment: You compute the standard deviation of the input samples, filter the input samples using the kalman filter, then compute the standard deviation of the output samples, using the formula described in your textbook, or on wikipedia, if it it too difficult to find it in your textbook.  Namely the square root of the mean (that's the average) of squares minus the square of the mean.  Then compare the two results.

Comment: But all my code is built in the form of iterations
If I take the error (between the true measurement and the estimate) obtained for each K and calculate the standard deviation for it, is this a mistake?

Comment: If you posted some code, it would be easier to give you a definitive answer.  For example, If you are looking for instantaneous RMS power, there are algorithms for this.  If you want to compute RMS power for blocks of samples at a time, a different algorithm is used.

Comment: I posted my code in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

the α−β−(γ)
filter, the Kalman filter utilizes the "Measure, Update, Predict" algorithm.

Contrary to the α−β−(γ)
filter, the Kalman Filter treats measurements, current state estimation, and next state estimation (predictions) as normally distributed random variables. The random variable is described by mean and variance.

Comment: Thanks. So for which variable should I calculate the standard deviation?
measurement? Update? Prediction? Error?

Comment: Can you explain me again which variable should I calculate the standard deviation ?